# Asymptotic equivalence and $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I  know that for $x\sim0$ $\sin x$ can be approximated by $x$, hence they are 'asymptotic equivalent in the neighborhood of $x=0$'.

According to the definition of asymptotic equivalence, two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ who are asymptotic equivalent in the neighbourhood of $x=0$ must satisfy the relationship

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$$

which indeed $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=x$ satisfy.

Now, my question is

> Can the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ also be justified using the definition of asymptotic equivalence?

Comment: It's equivalent. So the question is: *How* do you know that $\sin x$ can be approximated by $x$?

Comment: What's more the actual definition of equivalence is not this one, since f or g can be equal to 0 sometimes. More generally , f and g are equivalent around a point $x_o$ if :
f(x) -g(x) = o(g(x) , x->$x_o$
This definition is better, since g(x) or f(x) can take 0 as a value, which is not the case when you use the ration

Answer (score 3):

No, asymptotic equivalence doesn't justify the limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$. The limit justifies the equivalence.